# App works in Simulator but not on Device - NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with my app, which run well on the simulator but when I launch on my iDevice I got an error:

```
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
         reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'


    0   CoreFoundation                      0x3513cfd3 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x303928a5 objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x350bff99 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 472
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x350bfda7 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 34
    ....
    Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

In the debugger I can see where is the problem. The error comes from there, at the addObject:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayValues count]; i++) {
    f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    myNumber =[f numberFromString:[arrayValues objectAtIndex:i]];

    [arrayValues2 addObject:myNumber]; 
    [f release];    }
```

Here I convert objects of arrayValues (NSString) in NSNumbers in arrayValues2.

In the Simulator there is no problem, the arrays are not empties.
I don't know where to look for.

I also checked the other posts of stackoverflow, they are not really like my error

Comment: Where is the data in arrayValues coming from and is the data the same on the simulator and the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... I'm not sure what your problem is, but there is a much better way to do this...

```
for(NSString *theString in arrayValues){
    NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[theString floatValue]];
    [arrayValues2 addObject:aNumber];
}
```

which may help because you won't be outstepping any array boundaries, or inserting any nil objects.

If you want some more help you're going to have to NSLog arrayValues and give us the output so we can see what you're dealing with. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just working with the information you've given, it's not possible to pinpoint the problem (where is the data coming from?), but what we can say is that the exception gives a big clue:

You can't insert `nil` values into an array (use `NSNull` if you really need to).

Why is there a `nil` value? Well, when you try convert your string into a number it finds something it doesn't recognise. When that happens it returns a `nil`.

So you need to either sanitise your data (to make sure that everything *is* a number) or put error handling in your loop so that it doesn't try to put invalid values into the array.

(Also, [I agree with Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489339/app-works-in-simulator-but-not-on-device-nsmutablearray/4489400#4489400) about your implementation. His version will be easier to debug and use less memory.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I used Thomas's method, it's better than mine and it works :)